# Error in below python code

Tags: python

I am new to python program. the below code has some error with list.

```
len = []

def collatz_length(n,count):
                ++count
                if len[n]:
                        return len[n]
                if n == 1:
                        len[n] = count
                elif n & 1:
                        len[n] = count + collatz_length(3 * n + 1,0)
                else:
                        len[n] = count + collatz_length(n >> 1,0)

                return len[n]


print collatz_length(13,0)
```

i am trying to figure out the length.But the gives error

**OUTPUT**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "collatz.py", line 21, in <module>
    print collatz_length(13,0)
  File "collatz.py", line 9, in collatz_length
    if len[n]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: what is `++count`? Also `len` is a builtin method so best avoid using it as a variable name.

Answer (score 2):

It means that `n` is beyond the length of the list (which is initially zero). Rather than doing `len[n]`, you want to see if `n` is in your list:

```
# Renaming your array to my_array so that it doesn't shadow the len() function,
# It's also better to put it as a parameter, not a global
def collatz_length(n, count, my_array):
    if n < len(my_array):
        return my_array[n]
    # ... all your elses
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array with 5 things in it, and try to access array[5], you are reading outside the bounds of the array. I think that is what is happening, but your code is also very hard to understand. If that's not what is happening, you may need to add some comments or otherwise clarify what you are doing. It looks like you have an empty array and are trying to access location 13 in it, which makes no sense.